# How to set focus/active on the clicked li(tab) in angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have tab list where I'm trying to set class to the clicked list item (but class should be set only for clicked item) and my html looks like this:

```
 <div class="details-table">
    <ul class="table-toggle">
        <li class="active"><a href="" class="">Personal</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="" >Professional</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="scrollable-table-box">
        <table>
              ...
        </table>
     </div>
  </div>
```

And my css looks like this:

```
 .details-table {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
 }
 .table-toggle {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom: solid 5px #d9d9d9;
 }
 .table-toggle li {
     display: block;
     float: left;
     width: 220px;
     margin-right: 5px;
 }
 .table-toggle li a {
     color: #868686;
     display: block;
     font-size: 14px;
     padding: 15px 30px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
 }
 .table-toggle li:hover a,
 .table-toggle li.active a {
     background-color: #d9d9d9;
     color: #333;
     font-weight: 600;
 }
```

I want to set the focus to the clicked li item but I am not able to determine how I can do that ? I tried to use ng-click() but I am not sure how to set the focus to selected item inside that.

Comment: create a property in your object `isSelected` and set it true for clicked list and reset it for rest, and add ng-class on this condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply ng-class to determine the active item as below. Set activetab on your ng-click.

```
<li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'personal'}"><a href="#" ng-click="setActiveTab('personal')" class="">Personal</a></li>
<li ng-class="{active: activeTab == 'professional'}"><a href="#" ng-click="setActiveTab('professional')" class="" >Professional</a></li>
```

//JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);    
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.activeTab = 'personal';

  $scope.setActiveTab = function(value) {
    $scope.activeTab = value;
  };
});
```

Example Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ze7ps9XcNpLPHIs4I6Mi?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

in order to achieve that , you need to use angular directives **ng-click** and **ng-class**

1. inside your table toggle you change a little bit the li's elements (added ng-class in order to check the active li):

   ```
   <ul class="table-toggle">
       <li ng-class="{'active':selected == 'tab1'}" ng-click="select('tab1')"><a href="" class="">Personal</a></li>
       <li ng-class="{'active':selected == 'tab2'}" ng-click="select('tab2')"><a href="" class="" >Professional</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. into controller you just add a function that gets a tab parameter and a **selected** variable that holds the active li , each time.Default active li is the tab1(personal)

   ```
   $scope.selected = 'tab1';
     $scope.select = function(item){
        $scope.selected = item;
   }
   ```

live plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/TlKZNcDKMcOYDrGNcAch?p=preview

hope helps,good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```js
var m = [{
  isSelected: true,
  country: "India",
  index: "2"
}, {
  isSelected: false,
  country: "England",
  index: "2"
}, {
  isSelected: false,
  country: "Brazil",
  index: "3"
}, {
  isSelected: false,
  country: "UK",
  index: "1"
}, {
  isSelected: false,
  country: "USA",
  index: "3"
}, {
  isSelected: false,
  country: "Syria",
  index: "2"
}]

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = m;
  $scope.updateSelectedItem = function(item) {
    m.forEach(function(row) {
      row.isSelected = false;
    });
    item.isSelected = true;
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<h3>FIFA Mactch Summary:</h3>

<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in items" ng-class="{selected:i.isSelected == true}" ng-click="updateSelectedItem(i)">{{i.country}}: {{i.index}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```